# PDF/A-1b compliance whilst embedding OTF files

Tags: luatex, pdf, opentype, accessibility, pdfx

As per [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) wikipedia article (see `Fonts` section), only `pdf v1.6` and above is able to embed `opentype` fonts in the document.

Now the problem is that, my institution requires `pdf /A-1b` compliance which can be achieved through the `pdfx` package. The problem is that its [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf) discourages the use of an explicit option that sets this document version.

For example, if I need `pdf1.6`, I could have simply passed the option `pdf16` to the package. From the documentation of the package:

> pdf16: use PDF 1.6, overriding the version specified by the applicable standard.
>   This may produce a non-standard-conforming PDF file`

I am using `libertinus` open-type unicode fonts for my PhD thesis processed by `luatex` (TL 2018). The unix command `pdfinfo` says that the pdf version is only `1.5` which means the full `open-type` features are not present in the document.

I really wish to embed `opentype` fonts into the PDF whilst maintaining `PDF A/1-b` compliance. Can I achieve this somehow?

Comment: Which open type features are you missing in pdf1.5?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, all of the open-type features are missing in PDF 1.5.  For instance, see [this link](https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/version) (which supports the quote in the wikipedia link). As per this reference, `"Direct embedding of OpenType fonts – these no longer have to be embedded as TrueType or  Type 1 fonts."`

Comment: Sure but are you missing anything concretly? Beside this: using 1.6. *may* give an non conforming pdf. A small test with a short document showed that you need to use at least `\pdfvariable objcompresslevel=0`  when setting the pdf version to 1.6. More complicated documents could use more features that should be in a A1-b pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see. Hmm..... Perhaps I am better off using PDF/a-2 level of compliance. As per [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) wikipedia article, `"Part 2 of the standard, published on June 20, 2011, addresses some of the new features added with versions 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 of the PDF Reference. PDF/A-1 files will not necessarily conform to PDF/A-2, and PDF/A-2 compliant files will not necessarily conform to PDF/A-1.

Part 2 of the PDF/A Standard is based on a PDF 1.7 (ISO 32000-1), rather than PDF 1.4 and offers a number of new features"`. My university simply says "PDF/A"

Comment: I have a hunch that most universities actually don't know what they are asking for when they say "PDF/A". Certainly at my institution the text reads as though the thought "we want a PDF - but what if people don't know what a PDF is or we get people claiming all sorts is a PDF if they just have a file extension `.pdf`, let's include this ISO standard to cover our bases legally" They don't even mention the conformance level. So the question is whether or not anyone will actually check anything (or would even know how to do that!) as long as the thing you hand in is obviously a PDF.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Answer (score 2):

The internal way LuaLaTeX handles fonts automatically leads to PDF/A-1 compatible files – so there is no problem. This minimal example does not throw a font related validation error in Acrobat DC Preflight for PDF/A-1b when processed in LuaLaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\begin{document}
Text $\sqrt{3}$
\end{document}
```

I hope it's not too late for your PhD.

*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType

Comment: Also do you any reference that "PDF/A-1 requires TrueType"? As far as I know PDF/A-1 only requires the fonts to be embedded, so both TrueType and CFF should be fine. Actually your example demonstrated a CFF font.

Comment: I did not buy the standard. But [Wikipedia: PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A#PDF/A-2) states OpenType is allowed only from PDF/A-2 on. And my example not only validates Preflight but also VeraPDF.

Comment: Yes, but that refers to OpenType, not CFF/PostScript. There are multiple ways to embed OpenType fonts into PDF files: The traditional way which is used by LuaTeX, XeTeX etc. and which *is* allowed in PDF/A-1 extracts the inner TrueType or CFF font and embeds that into the PDF directly. The other (not allowed) variant is that in newer PDF versions OpenType fonts can be embedded directly, without extracting the TrueType or CFF part first. This only works in PDF 1.6 and is therefore not allowed in PDF/A-1, but that isn't relevant for LuaTeX: LuaLaTeX doesn't use that format anyway.

Comment: I adjusted the answer.